# Problem while using react native socket io client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket io in my React native chat app. When I open the screen for the first time it works perfectly but when I navigate back to other screens all the API calls are getting slower and my chat screen also gets slow.

Also, the message received from the ***socket*** is received instantly but if I emit a message it's taking to much time ***(more than 15 seconds)***

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socketConnection.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to server');
      joinChat();
    });

    if (socketConnection) {
      setSocket(socketConnection);
    }

    socketConnection.on('private message', async function (data) {
      try {
        console.log(' ~ data:', data);
        const obj = {from: 1, message: data?.message, time: date, to: username};
        setChats([...chats, obj]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating chat data:', error);
      }
    });

    socketConnection.on('error', error => {
      console.error('Socket connection error:', error);
    });

    return () => {
      socketConnection.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```